# How to stop plastic panels below windows making popping noises as they warm up

Tags: windows, pvc, noise-reduction

We have plastic panels below our bedroom windows like in the photo. In the summer when the sun rises they make loud popping and cracking noises as they warm up.  What can we do to stop or reduce the noise?

[image: window panel]

Comment: Is the trim around the plastic panel also plastic?  The panel is likely expanding with the temperature change.  If you cut the panel smaller and make the trim bigger to hide the gap and allow it more room to expand maybe you won't have noise.  You'd have to make sure you determine exactly which part of the assembling is making the noise.  You could replace with wood but even wood will expand.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger yes the trim is also plastic

Comment: are the trim pieces caulked to the panel?  it could be that the caulking is preventing the panel from expanding.   one thing to try is to cut the caulking, if with the caulking cut the noises go away then you could try to caulk after the panel is at full expansion with a maximally expanding caulk like "big stretch" caulk.

Comment: Thanks @FreshCodemonger I'll look into that.

Comment: Any chance of more pictures, from more angles?

Comment: That only happens if the panel has no place to expand